# How to use Ajax in ASP.NET for Email ID validation? Help me

Tags: asp.net, ajax

How to use Ajax in ASP.NET for Email ID validation.

Comment: Can you give more details about your problem? not clear

Comment: @rajasekar then dont expect anyone to answer your question. I think I should remove my answer now ;-)

Comment: @Rajasekar - won't, or can't?

Comment: Let's all assume "can't" since there's a language barrier in play here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression to validate an email **format** . Here is an article about that. [How to Find or Validate an Email Address](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) . You can add a regular expression validator and set the required regular expression.

If you are looking for validating an email (exist or does not exist) then there is no other way other than sending the email and checking if it bounces back.

[Here is not article for .net](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/validation/Valid_Email_Addresses.aspx) and [about regular expression validator](http://www.devhood.com/Tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=46)

Please explain more if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not give a specific case. 
so let me share my registration page code snippet. 
Here is how I use ajax to check if an email address has been registered.

on register.aspx page:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel_CheckEmail" 
  UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">

  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="LblEmail" AssociatedControlID="TxtEmail" 
      runat="server">
      <span>*</span>Email:
    </asp:Label>

    <!-- Server side validation -->
    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtEmail" 
       ontextchanged="TxtEmail_TextChanged" 
       AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />

    <small>
      <asp:Literal ID="LblEmailStatus" runat="server" Text="" />
    </small>

    <!-- Client side validation -->
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="TxtEmailRegEx" runat="server" 
       ErrorMessage="Enter a valid email address to sign up"
       ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" 
       ControlToValidate="TxtEmail" />

  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

on register.aspx.cs:

```
protected void TxtEmail_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Server side validation
    if ( EmailRegistered(TxtEmail.txt) )
    {
       LblEmailStatus.Text = "use other email!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtEmail").blur(function () {

            var prmList = '';
            prmList += '{"emailAddress":"' + $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtEmail").val() + '"}';
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: window.location.pathname + "/CheckEmailId",
                data: prmList,
                async: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    if (msg.d == 'true') {
                        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblUserEmailExist").html('This email is already exists.');
                        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkbtnSave").hide();

                    }
                    else {
                        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblUserEmailExist").html('Valid email id');
                        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkbtnSave").show();

                    }
                    //                    alert(msg.d);

                    //window.location = "../DataEntry/AddMemberList.aspx";
                },
                error: function (msg) { }
            });

        });

    });
</script>
```

code-behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string CheckEmailId(string emailAddress)
{
    string isExitst = string.Empty;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(emailAddress))
    {
        if (FetchEmailID(emailAddress))
            isExitst = "true";

        else
            isExitst = "false";
    }
    return isExitst;
}
public static bool FetchEmailID(string emailAddress)
{
    bool isExist = false;
    DowEntities dataContext = new Entities();
    TblDataEntry data = new TblDataEntry();
    var rec  = (from m in dataContext.TblDataEntries where m.Email == emailAddress select m).ToList();
    //data = dataContext.TblDataEntries.Where(x => x.Email == emailAddress).ToList();
    if (rec.Count() > 0 && rec.First().Email == emailAddress)
    {
        isExist = true;

    }
    else
    {
        isExist = false;

    }
    return isExist;
}
```